# Why do Javascript programmers prefer repeating strings for constants in their code to using an enum type objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why Javascript programmers don't see the value in using an enum-like object to represent constant values rather than repeating strings throughout their code?  For example:

```
foo.addEventListener("someEvent", function(event) { .... });
```

vs

```
foo.addEventListener(events.someEvent, function(event) { .... });
```

To me the second seems superior because a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) would have a better chance of working out when you pass in invalid values (if it can see the declaration of `events`).

The arguments I'm hearing in favour of strings are basically along the lines of "this is just how javascript programmers do it" which irks me because it seems to fly in the face of the best practice in practically every other language I have ever worked in.

So please help me understand: is this a case of my trying to foist my C habits on JS developers - do I need to learn to change my ways?

Comment: OK so people are voting to close?  Its a genuine question and there must be some reasonable answers out there...I'm not trying to start a flame war.

Comment: Your question calls for opinions. This isn't a discussion board. So vote to close. Sorry.

Comment: @Yoshi: No opinions.  OK.  This place has gone down hill...programming is a subjective art by nature...there is NO right answer to everything.

Comment: "...this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.". The answer is "It depends".

Comment: *To me the second seems superior...* <- there is the opinion. *programming is a subjective art by nature* that may be, but this is not the place to discuss such a thing.

Comment: @Yoshi: better get to work then...if there are not allowed to be any opinions on here you have your work cut out.  I think that is very sad.   It didn't used to be this way here (I'm a very long-time member).

Comment: @Yoshi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423739/whats-the-best-way-of-ensuring-valid-object-lifespan-when-using-boost-asio - close?  I used the word "best" in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't, but I think the issue is that many JS coders don't realize that you can (ab)use associative arrays to give an enum-like effect.

```
var events = {
    someEvent : "someEvent",
    someOtherEvent : "someOtherEvent"
}

foo(events.someEvent);
```

It's definitely good practice to do it this way and avoids a lot of coding headaches.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript property lookups can potentially be expensive (scope traversal plus long prototype chains).

And I've yet to see a static analyzer (including JSLint) actually pick up on the contents of an object.

Personally I like your method, but it comes at a tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure who told you but I personally have taken a class focused on Web Development and they do recommend that you do put variables in global scope as constants rather than constantly typing the String over and over again. It causes less headaches, is a lot more organized, and in some cases can even help with scalability.

However, I will say that in general it's ideal (this is seen in all coding languages as you probably know) to avoid global variables if you can. Ideally if you don't need to make it global and keep it local, then you should do it. If you find yourself passing a variable around or using a constant over and over again that won't change, then yeah might as well put it in a variable.

Bottom line: You don't need to change your ways. Actually I bet you the reason a lot of JS developers don't have these good practices is because of how flexible javascript is. I'm sure if a lot of JS developers were to learn Java or C as their first language, they would also have these good habits.

Answer (score 0):

because you would have to add your variable `events` in the global/clusure scope.

but in javascript you should always keep your variables in local scope, because that is much faster.

Comment: Thats not always true - you can add your enum to some top-level global where you scope all your code.

Comment: Also, is performance really going to suffer that much?  Most of the performance problems I have seen these have seen (writing webapps at least) are in the rendering code.

Comment: yes, but the js-engine has nevertheless to jump up the scope chain, except you define your enum in the same function scope as the code, where you call it.

Comment: this performance is just important, if you want to write a single wep page application, otherwise you dont have to care about that really.